# CSS Dropdown Remove Text Wrap

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

How do I remove text wrapping for the child elements in a dropdown?

JSFiddle with CSS here: http://jsfiddle.net/6Bqfn/4/

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Shop</a>
 <ul class="children">
    <li><a href="#">Longer Title</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I can't get the ul holding the children elements to resize to the size of the largest child li.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `white-space:nowrap;` in your css for the items you wish not to wrap:

```
ul.children li {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

This will force all items to show up on a single line, and since all your widths are set to auto, it'll expand accordingly. I updated your jsFiddle as well.

Comment: "Note: The value 'inherit' is not supported in IE7 and earlier. IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE. IE9 supports 'inherit'."[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) ~I would not worry about it, but I thought I would let you know before you bang your head wondering why IE7 was not working.

Comment: those were pre-existing in the CSS ... I just literally added the code above. obviously it wasn't a problem before.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple. I was trying text-wrap:none; and it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like embedding a non-breaking space...

```
<a href="#">Longer&nbsp;Title</a>
```